# Unable to set ms-TS-Max-Idle-Time LDAP attribute

Tags: active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2016

I need help with an LDAP attribute that I’m trying to assign for adding a new AD user.

I’m using the following Python script for adding a new user and everything works as expected:

```
    # sample attributes
    ldap_attr = {}
    ldap_attr['objectClass'] = ['top', 'person' , 'organizationalPerson' , 'user' ]
    ldap_attr['cn'] = user_username
    ldap_attr['givenName'] = user_firstname
    ldap_attr['sn'] = user_lastname
    ldap_attr['uid'] = user_username
    ldap_attr['sAMAccountName'] = user_username
    ldap_attr['mail'] = user_email
    ldap_attr['telephoneNumber'] = user_phonenumber
    ldap_attr['userPrincipalName'] = f"{user_username}@{ad_domain}"
    ldap_attr['displayName'] = f"{user_firstname} {user_lastname}"
    ### SCRIPT PATH
    ldap_attr['scriptPath'] = 'sto.bat'
    ### SESSION TIMEOUTS
    ldap_attr['msTSMaxDisconnectionTime'] = 1
    ldap_attr['msTSMaxIdleTime'] = 120
    ldap_attr['msTSReconnectionAction'] = True

    ldap_conn = connect_ldap_server()
    response = ldap_conn.add(f'CN={user_username},{users},{base}', attributes=ldap_attr)
```

However, the following attributes listed in that script aren’t being added to that user related to Terminal Service.

- msTSMaxDisconnectionTime
- msTSMaxIdleTime
- msTSReconnectionAction

I’m using the correct LDAP name and value type based on the supported Microsoft documentation found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-mstsmaxidletime

I’m not sure if there is anything that needs to be set on the AD domain controller itself or anything I need to define differently within my script. But any help is much appreciated because I’m unable to find any results related to my issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Which Python LDAP module are you using – `ldap3` or `python-ldap`? Does the add() call raise an exception? If it doesn't, what does `response` contain?